# Image is not loaded on A-frame

Tags: aframe

I tried to replicate the example (https://aframe.io/examples/showcase/sky/) but no image is loaded, there is no load as texture or background. I tried all the files ".js" on github like in the source but none worked for me.

https://glitch.com/~aframe-basic-guide-with-environment here is a code and it seems that it has the same problem

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question, and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is correct, it was just an old library you were loading.
Once you change that, it works:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/quixotic-thirsty-time?path=index.html:6:49